# GCP log-based metrics error: REQUEST_CONTEXT_READ

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-monitoring

Loading log-based metrics suddenly stopped working with this error:

```
An error occurred requesting data. Can not find metric metric_types: "logging.googleapis.com/user/<redacted>" resource_container_ids: <redacted> request_context: REQUEST_CONTEXT_READ
```

[image: log-based metric error in GCP console]

Alerts defined on this metric are still triggering properly.
Any idea what can be the cause of this error? And since it was working before, perhaps this is a GCP bug?

Comment: This is a ongoing issue, you can monitor the status on this [Issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/199481019).